# pixel data is NULL only after seeking to frame 0

Tags: ios, avplayer, core-video

I'm trying to buffer video frames one at a time using this:

```
CGFloat frameTimeSeconds = 1/self.fps * frame;
CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(frameTimeSeconds, self.player.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale);
CVPixelBufferRef nonSeekPixelBuffer = [self.videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:frameTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
if (nonSeekPixelBuffer != NULL) {
    completion(nonSeekPixelBuffer);
    return;
}
[self.player seekToTime:frameTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
     if (finished) {
         CVPixelBufferRef didSeekPixelBuffer = [weakSelf.videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:frameTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
         completion(didSeekPixelBuffer);
     }
}];
```

This approach works fine for except when frame 0 (and only frame 0) isn't immediately available and we need to be seek to it. When seeking to `frameTimeSeconds == 0`, `didSeekPixelBuffer` is always `NULL`, without fail. I've tried using different timescales when making `frameTime`, I've tried using `kCMTimeZero` when `frame` == 0, but they all have the same result.

My current workarounds are either A: cache frame zero when the video first loads and use then whenever frame ==0, or seek to slightly less than frame 1

This may be related to another issue I'm having - if I load frames in a random order, I am able to get frame data for each frame (aside from 0) with no problem, but I'll get a ton of duplicates. Trying to load frames sequentially gives me frame data with no issues.

Comment: What happens if you relax the seek zero tolerance? Or if you use `seekToTime:`?

Comment: I wasn't particularly able to fix it, but I was able to work around it. I ended up sorting my seek events ahead of time and threw out sequential seek requests (where desired frame == last frame buffered + 1). That cut down on my seek events a ton. I also put in a timeout checking dispatch block to unstall the frame buffering queue.

Comment: I don't think I can relax the seek tolerance, I need to the frame accuracy for my purposes, but I will try the non-callback version and `seekToTime:`